# How to solve "DriverClass not found for database:mariadb" with AWS data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to play with AWS Data Pipelines (and then Glue later) and am following [Copy MySQL Data Using the AWS Data Pipeline Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-mysql-console.html). However, when I execute the pipeline, I get

```
DriverClass not found for database:mariadb
```

I would expect this to "just work," but why is it not providing it's own driver? Or is driver for MySQL not equal to driver for MariaDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, after fighting with this all day, I found the following link which solves it: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=834603&tstart=0

Basically:
You are getting the error because you are using the RdsDatabase, it needs to be the JdbcDatabase when using mariadb.

"type": "JdbcDatabase",
"connectionString": "jdbc:mysql://thing-master.cpbygfysczsq.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/db_name",
"jdbcDriverClass" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

FULL credit goes to Webstar34 (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/profile.jspa?userID=452398)